# Find cross-account (trusted account) relationships via the AWS API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

We are looking to access multiple trusted accounts via the AWS API in .Net. We know we can find child accounts within the organization with one of the api calls. However, we don't need the child accounts of the organization. We need to find the trusted accounts we have association with. How can we do that via the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IAM get role API for all the existing IAM roles in your account.

This API response has AssumeRolePolicyDocument which can let you know the list of other accounts to whom trust relationship is established.

Sample AssumeRoleDocument

```
 'Role': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::12345678900:role/test_cross_acct_role',
  'AssumeRolePolicyDocument': {'Statement': [{'Action': 'sts:AssumeRole',
     'Condition': {'StringEquals': {'sts:ExternalId': 'test123'}},
     'Effect': 'Allow',
     'Principal': {'AWS': 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:root'}}],
   'Version': '2012-10-17'},
```